# Facebooker with authlogic, problem with script/generate xd_receiver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, facebooker

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect#readme and getting stuck at the

$ script/generate xd_receiver

line. It gives an error:

Couldn't find 'xd_receiver' generator

I read up on similar issues, which said to install the typhoeus gem. I did that and I also made sure that my facebook.yml file was up to date.

What else might be the problem? What exactly does it mean it can't find the generator- that it's not part of an installed gem??

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this was an issue with the deployment and server setup.